# Wrong subtitle show

Tags: windows, subtitles

i have problem with every subtitle i download from any sites the subtitle shows like this in notepad: ÊÑÌãå: íÇÓÇä
what must i do to fix this i try to change encoding but nothing happens.
also realized this must be in my Os because this will not happen in my firends laptop(windows 7)
my os is: windows 8.1
thanks
note: i want show this subtitles as persian/farsi language.

Comment: when i say change encoding i mean change in note pad to unicod or UFT-8......

Comment: `notepad`, menu `Format` -> `Font...`, item `Script`

Answer (score 0):

ok i solve my problem with going to control panle--> change date, time , or format numbers---> adminstrative-->change system local to my language